# hibernate search @ContainedIn not working on boolean fields

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I'm trying to index a field in an indexedembedded object and for some reason it's not updating. I have a convenience retrieval method as the part annotated with @IndexedEmbedded, but the other attribute I'm indexing does seem to trigger a change. I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Here's the basic configuraiton:

```
ClassA {

    List<ClassB> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    @IndexedEmbedded
    ClassB getNewestClassB() {
         //sort by creationDate and return last
    } 
}

ClassB {

    @Field
    enum myEnum;

    @Field
    Boolean myBool; //Boolean to avoid null issues

    @ContainedIn
    ClassA

    boolean getMyBool() {
        if(myBool == null)
            return false;

        return myBool;
    }
}
```

If I update myEnum it updates the index and even actually fixes the seemingly lost myBool update. I tried annotating both the field itself and the getter to see if for some reason the potential for null was throwing it off, but that didn't help. I also tried using BooleanBridge on both, but no luck there either.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Could you try to write a self contained test case using our test case template: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene ? Thanks!

Comment: I'll start setting one up. Thanks! Also, one thing I forgot to mention is that I'm using hibernate search 5.3 due to my spring boot having an older hibernate vesion that required 5.3 tied to it.

Comment: That's probably a bug in the dirty checking strategies; could you try disabling these by setting "hibernate.search.enable_dirty_check = false" ? It will be slightly less efficient, but I think it would workaround your problem (and help us narrow it down)

Comment: @Sanne No luck unfortunately. I only tested on the field, not the getter, unless you guys think that would be worth it, but it's updating the index to a certain extent. When I start, looking in Luke, the freq of the myBool terms is 2, and after I make the change, it's 3, just they're all the initial value. When I change myEnum, the freq of myBool changes to 2 original and 1 updated. This seems to be happening with both the dirty checking false and commented out.

Comment: @AndrewRobie any progress on the test case? Thanks!

Comment: @GuillameSmet Making some progress, but still need to finish up. What should I do for the Jira Key? Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet I wrote up a test case using the template, but it passed. I'm not sure if it has to do with using an older version of Hibernate Search or something else, like that I'm using JpaRepos and Transactional annotation instead of explicit transactions like the template. I'm going to keep playing around with it, try setting up JPA and switching the version, but is there anything I should keep in mind?

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Actually got it working (failing) quicker than I expected. It was to do with the class referenced by the indexed object being a child class of the class that actually contains the indexed boolean field. Need to check about the enum part, but how do I get the test case and the supporting classes to you?

Comment: @AndrewRobie open a JIRA here and attach the project reproducing the error: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa . Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewRobie any progress on this? It would be nice to have it logged in the bugtracker so that we don't forget about it. Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Sorry, work's been really busy. I can log the ticket a little later today hopefully, but I probably won't be able to get back to the test cases until next week.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Sorry it's taken a while. The enum update also doesn't seem to be working now. Do you want me to update the test case I have so you can see if there's something I'm missing or if there's something or if there's something to it? Or would you rather I set up the test case more like my project, like using JpaRepo implementations instead?

Comment: @AndrewRobie If you reproduced it with our test case template, I would rather like a test case using our template. Easier to debug without specific stuff or other frameworks! Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet So I may have just wasted like a month. It looks like the issue was related to this [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=855948). I overrode the getter on the parent class and annotated that with the field annotation and it seems to be working now. I don't know why the enum was getting it to update, since that was also on the parent class, so go figure. I can keep trying to get the test case set up in regards to the enum vs. boolean if you think it'd be worth anything. I'll keep trying to get that test case for the other issue I have open working, though.

Comment: @AndrewRobie mmmmh, you never talked about programmatic mapping and your example used annotations. Are you using programmatic mapping? If you use annotations, it should work. Please make a test case so that we can take a look because it's really difficult to discuss something I can't see by myself. Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet [Here's the JIRA with the test case](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2486). I'm still not quite sure why the enum is causing an update in my project but not the test, so I'll keep looking into that, but I wanted to finally get what I do have to you since it's taken me a while. Let me know if there's anything more you need. In the meantime, I'll try to figure that out as well as the term range vs. numeric range thing from my other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AndrewRobie, we were able to track the issue and fix it.

See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2486 for more information about it.

The fix will be part of our next releases: 5.5.6.Final and 5.6.0.CR1.